# Liquibase Maven update Fails with Type Incompatibility Error

Tags: mysql, maven, liquibase

I am running through the tutorial of liquibase being new. After following instructions I am able to run `liquibase update` command with no issues, but if I try `mvn liquibase:update` I receive the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.9.0:update (default-cli) on project LiquibaseDemoMysql: A type incompatibility occurred while executing org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.9.0:update: class java.time.LocalDateTime cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.time.LocalDateTime and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.9.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/duart/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-maven-plugin/3.9.0/liquibase-maven-plugin-3.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/duart/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.23/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/duart/.m2/repository/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.11.4/protobuf-java-3.11.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/duart/.m2/repository/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/1.0/cdi-api-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/C:/Users/duart/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.inject/0.3.2/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/C:/Users/duart/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-builder-support/3.3.9/maven-builder-support-3.3.9.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/C:/Users/duart/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/C:/Users/duart/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/1.0.2.v20150114/aether-util-1.0.2.v20150114.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/C:/Users/duart/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/4.0/guice-4.0-no_aop.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/C:/Users/duart/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/C:/Users/duart/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.21/plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/C:/Users/duart/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/C:/Users/duart/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.6/plexus-component-annotations-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/C:/Users/duart/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.3/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/C:/Users/duart/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/C:/Users/duart/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.4/commons-lang3-3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/C:/Users/duart/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.9.0/liquibase-core-3.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/C:/Users/duart/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.0/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/C:/Users/duart/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.24/snakeyaml-1.24.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/C:/Users/duart/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/C:/Users/duart/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.3/logback-core-1.2.3.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Not sure what is causing this and haven't been able to find anything online regarding this. Has anyone had this issue and no how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I updated the version of the liquibase-maven-plugin from 3.9.0 to the latest. The version they have you. the version given in the tutorial is outdated.